# UIWebView Orientation Problems

Tags: ios, uiwebview, storyboard

I am looking into an app with split screen web views for comparison. Is there a way of keeping the size and positioning of these and just having the content rotate when changing the orientation?

for example, two pictures on top of each other each taking up half of the screen in portrait then when turning to landscape the pictures would sit side by side again taking up half the screen.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
    {
        // Return YES for supported orientations
        return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
    }
```

The above function helps you to make your orientations in desired manner, but this will not layout your UIObjects, So if you want your images to appear properly in portrait and landscape mode, you should set its **frame** accordingly in both modes and it will solve your problem.

Comment: sorry I'm new to this, What's the best way to set the frames for both modes? and will this still work if I use a tab bar controller?

Comment: You should check the in what mode the device is (portrait or landscape and set you frames).It will work in case of tab bar controller also.To set frames use CGRect